# Getting Specific Cell Value from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView populated from a SQL table, and would like to get the info from a specific cell, i.e. from row 4 column 2.  How would I go about doing this?  Is it something like `specialPricingSheetGridView.DataKeys[row,column]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to directly access the cell value like so:

```
string txt = specialPricingSheetGridView.Rows[4].Cells[2].Text;
```